# XML change tag name using Python

Tags: python, xml, tags

Very new to XML and Python. I want to change the tag names of certain elements in an XML document. Here's how the document looks now:

```
<Company>
   <Employee>
      <SSN>111111111</SSN>
      <Dependent>
          <SSN>222222222</SSN>
```

I want to change the tag under the Employee to 'EESSN' and leave the tag under the Dependent the same. To look like this.

```
<Company>
   <Employee>
      <EESSN>111111111</EESSN>
      <Dependent>
          <SSN>222222222</SSN>
```

The document includes hundreds of companies and thousands of employees both with tens to hundreds of sub elements, so a find and replace option is what I believe I need.

I want to use ElementTree module. The only code I have that is working is the importing the data and writing it to a new file. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: "I want to use ElementTree module." --- Why don't you just use [tag:XSLT]?

Comment: Use the [the-parse-function](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function) and do `element.tag = '<new tag name>'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use ElementTree, you can find all `SSN` elements that are children of `Employee` and set `tag`.

Example...

**Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<Company>
    <Employee>
        <SSN>111111111</SSN>
        <Dependent>
            <SSN>222222222</SSN>
        </Dependent>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xml")

for elem in tree.findall("Employee/SSN"):
    elem.tag = "EESSN"

tree.write("output.xml")
```

**Output** (output.xml)

```xml
<Company>
    <Employee>
        <EESSN>111111111</EESSN>
        <Dependent>
            <SSN>222222222</SSN>
        </Dependent>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

Comment: Works great Daniel. Thanks  man. Great help! Did you happen to see my other question posted yesterday, "How do I copy and paste certain elements in XML using Python". I think the answer might be along the same lines as what you showed me here as far as finding the elements. Now I want to copy them and append to other elements. Thanks!